# Asus X556UAM no HDMI video output

Tags: 16.04, video, intel-graphics, hdmi, asus

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on ASUS X566UMA laptop. 
I'm struggling to make my external screens work. VGA output works fine, but once I want to extend my screen for two screens simultaneously through VGA and HDMI, the HDMI one doesn't get any effect.

I tried to update my drivers by Intel Graphic Update Tool, didn't help much.

Any ideas what might cause the problem?

The output of `sudo lshw -C video` is:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
   resources: irq:128 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

http://pastebin.com/RDVg9w1h  output of `xrandr --verbose`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. **;-)** Could be a number of items, but we won't know until you list the hardware you have, so [edit] your question and provide the output to `sudo lshw -C video`.

Comment: I've just added needed content

Comment: Weird.  Shut down the machine, then hook it up to HDMI, then boot, then provide the output to `xrandr --verbose`

Comment: I've done like you said, content of that command is added.  Cable is connected but it seems that it doesn't recognise it.

Comment: It does recognize it as you have a 3840 x 1080 screen (twice 1920 x 1080)  Try another cable first. (Is the secondary screen a TV or a monitor?)

Comment: It is my new dev station. Laptop with two additional screens. One through VGA, second VGA > VGA to HDMI  adaptor > HDMI.

Cables are alright because before I switched to Ubuntu on Windows everything was working just fine.

Comment: HDMI adapter? Maybe that has a Windows driver that does not exist under Ubuntu. try going direct VGA.